# Insertion of Data in English and Arabic in one column in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

Hi I want to Insert a data that is in Persian And English  the  string  that I want to insert  is `'(پایه ۱۹۸=OID) -عبوری-متوسط'`
but it shows ??????  instead of the data ... I want to insert the data by stored Procedure  My stored Procedure is

```
USE [DAT1]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SP_insert]    Script Date: 7/25/2018 3:32:46 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

SET ANSI_WARNINGS off;
GO

ALTER proc [dbo].[SP_insert]
@FirstName nvarchar(256) = null,
@LastName  nvarchar(50),
@EmailAddress nvarchar (50),
@phone int  
as
begin 
insert into [tbl_test ] values (@FirstName,@LastName,@EmailAddress,@phone)

end
```

when I execute the procedure using N it works but the data comes from an app and I can't put N

in ADO.net I Want to Insert that data  here is My code

```
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_insert", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


        string mmmm = "(پایه 198=OID) -عبوری-متوسط";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", mmmm);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", "ascascsacsa");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAddress", "advadsvasdv");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", 1);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
```

when I execute the Code It shows the Error

```
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.
```

how can I solve this Thanks :)

Comment: The app code must be changed, either adding the `N` for Unicode literals or by using parameterized queries with SQL data type `nvarchar`. There isn't anything you can do unilaterally on the server side. Also, do not use prefix `sp_` for user stored procs as that denotes system stored procedures.

Comment: @DanGuzman how can I put N from app

Comment: No need for `N` with your parameterized query because .NET strings are Unicode. The truncation error is due to the target table columns being too small for the values. Check the column max size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database is just storing what it's receiving and it will store the desired characters just fine with your current setup if the tables are set to use N types (so check that too). Alter your application code to use a wider character set.

Comment: HOW TO CAN I PUT n from application ??

Comment: Try something like the following:
`cmd.Parameters.Add("@title", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = TextBox1.Text.Trim();`

Comment: what error? did you tailor it to your example? Also, if you are editing the original post you should show where edits are made so that people can follow easier

Comment: String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: you haven't changed your parameter adding like I said you should try. Use add and not addwithvalue. In the add you provide the sqldbtype you are wanting to use. The third parameter in the add is the length that you want to use for the nvarchar so decide what you would like it to be. `cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 500).value = mmmm;`

Comment: what is the length of the nvarchar on your column?

Comment: 256 length is 256 for table

Comment: thanks, Guys  the problem was length of Nvarchar tnx :)